# Change event not firing when using radio button with VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events

I'd like to handle an event when a different radio button is selected in Vue. The code snippet of my initial solution is shown below

**HTML File**

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="m" @change="filterChanged">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="f" @change="filterChanged">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" id="All" name="gender" value="a" @change="filterChanged">
  <label for="all">All</label>
</div>
```

**JS File**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    filterChanged() {
      console.log('You changed the filter');
    }
  }
});
```

However, whenever I select a different radio button, the `filterChanged()` function is never called. I'm trying to shy away from using `v-model` since this is handling of a more general event (the change of selection among the options). Is there anything I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: works in jsfiddle

Comment: I would check for any spelling or syntax errors because that should be working

Comment: I think   <input type="radio" id="All" name="gender" value="a" @change="filterChanged()">
should work. Note the () to call the method.

Comment: Go down the road of `v-model` . Huge parts of VueJS is built around `v-model`. Also consider Bootstrap-Vue: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio

Answer (score 0):

You have made mistake in `data: {},` it should be in `data(){...}`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {},
  methods: {
    filterChanged() {
      console.log("You changed the filter");
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the working sandbox for your code:

[Code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-rain-fr391?file=/src/App.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I found that when there was something else changing the radio button (eg. radio button being set via a prop() or something) rather than a true human click, the change event wasn't actually fired.

If you set `@click()` instead of `@change()` see if that helps it start firing.

Your code does look correct though, so if you can get JS to not fire it, then that's most ideal.

Answer (score -3):

Agree with Aaron, it's a function you're calling, so use: `filterChanged()`
Also, try using  `v-on:click="filterChanged()"`

In theory, that shouldn't make a difference, but I've found that can help sometimes.

Comment: I don't downvote, but this answer is wrong. Vue event handlers can either be method names `filterChanged` _or_ executable code `filterChanged()`